# Program hangs up after loop counter input - no infinite loop or seg fault

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue I can't figure out how to diagnose. It's been a while since I've worked in C++ and I decided to write a class based implementation of a LLL, with one class for the node and one for the list for the sake of practice. Once the list has been initialized in main, it prompts the user to input the length of the list from within the constructor. Then, for some reason, it hangs up instead of generating the list. I haven't gotten any error codes, and it doesn't seem to be stuck in a loop as best as I can tell. I'm very confused.

Main function:

```
int main() {
    LLL *  myList = new LLL();
    int displayCount = 0;
    displayCount = myList->display();
    cout << "\n\n" << displayCount << " nodes were displayed\n\n";
    delete myList;

    return 0;

}
```

LLL constructor:

```
LLL::LLL() {
    head = new node(rand() % 20);
    node * current = head;
    cout << "\n\nHow many nodes would you like this list to be? ";
    int length = 0;
    cin >> length;
    cin.ignore(1000);
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i) {
            node * temp = new node(rand() % 20);
            current->attachNext(temp);
            current = temp;
            delete temp;
}
```

Node constructor:

```
node::node(int data) {
    this->next = NULL;
    this->data = data;
}
```

attachNext function:

```
bool node::attachNext(node *& toAttach) {
    this->next = toAttach;
    return true;

}
```

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    node();
    node(int data);
    ~node();
    node * traverse();//returns obj->next node
    bool checkNext();//returns true if obj->next exists
    bool attachNext(node *& toAttach);
    int display();
    int deleteAll(int & count);
private:
    node * next;
    int data;
};

class LLL {
public:

    LLL();
    LLL(int length);
    ~LLL();
    int display();

private:

    node * head;


};
```

Comment: You delete the nodes in LLL's constructor. Remove the line "delete temp" and it will work a lot better.

Comment: Your code is still not buildable. destructors and display are missing.  I copy over your code and test it here https://segfault.stensal.com/a/Qkfe98tSNtkhkSdu, If you can fix the compilation error for the missing display function. You should be able to see what causes the segfault.

Comment: The destructor isn't missing, I just didn't include it because it isn't called at this point in the program and therefore isn't relevant to the issue. The same goes for display and all the other functions listed in the header file that I didn't include the code for

Comment: Ian, I deleted that line and the hangup still occurs. I don't think the program is even reaching the loop, but I can't figure out why. Also, I believe that if that line is missing, it will cause a memory leak, though it's possible I don't remember that correctly.

Comment: It looks like you do a lot of memory allocation/deallocation which you could avoid by just using stack variables, and you use raw pointers and `new`/`delete` which are very error prone. As you've seen this probably isn't the problem in this case, but there could be other bugs caused by these and they make it harder to read, harder to maintain, and slower.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I called the cin.ignore function in the LLL and forgot to specify the delimiter.

This:

```
cin.ignore(1000);
```

Should have been:

```
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
```